# Paste using array ignore blank cells

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Thank to some of the people on this forum I have this code working to copy multiple cells from a reference active sheet to a master worksheet while transposing them. The only problem I have is that there is one range that has blank cells and I would like the function to ignore those. I have tried using the `specialpaste` function with `skipblanks=true` but that doesn't help. Any suggestions?

```
Macro1()
Dim master As Worksheet, source As Worksheet, copyCols() As Variant, pasteCols() As Variant, i As Integer

Set master = Workbooks("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
Set source = ActiveSheet
copyCols = Array("F", "H", "N", "R", "S")
pasteCols = Array("B", "L", "V", "AF", "AP")

For i = 0 To UBound(copyCols)
    source.Range(copyCols(i) & "4:" & copyCols(i) & 14).Copy
    master.Range(pasteCols(i) & master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A quick google search of "PasteSpecial Skipblanks fails" reveals that the blank cells are not pasted (see [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/why-does-skip-blanks-paste-special-function-not-work-t3632226.html) for instance). This means, if there is content at the destination range that otherwise would had been overwritten by a blank cell, `Skipblanks` keeps it intact. Would you like to *eliminate* (remove) the blank cells of the origin range instead?

Comment: @Ioannis good question ...or skip over blanks in the destination maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Select the non blanks cells by selecting SpecialCells with type Constants, then paste the results, which will only past the selected cells.

Try the code the code below.

```
copyCols = Array("D", "E")
pasteCols = Array("H", "I")

For i = 0 To UBound(copyCols)
    Range(copyCols(i) & "4:" & copyCols(i) & 14).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Copy
    Range(pasteCols(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll,     Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
Next i
```